# Apache serving static file request

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have configured Apache web server which passes the request to Weblogic App Server on context root /2d

```
ProxyPass /2d http://exlhamppatgc.2degreesmobile.co.nz:7003/2d
ProxyPassReverse /2d http://exlhamppatgc.2degreesmobile.co.nz:7003/2d
```

Now I want to serve static files (gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf) from Apache and request should be served first from Apache htdoc folder first. If file is not there then look for app server.

Comment: Try `ProxyPassMatch .*\.(?i)(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ !` to excluded static files. Another way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443742/how-to-server-static-files-proxy-context

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a conditional rewrite. Depending on the exact path requirements, something like (untested):

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENTROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule /2d/((.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf))$ /path/to/docroot/$1 [L]
```